# Is there a simplified pytz common_timezone list?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm hoping someone has come up with something like this.

There's about 400+ timezones in the pytz.common_timezones list, and while that's great for accuracy, it's quite a bit too much to ask users to sift through.

See for instance, this timezone list from a forum I frequent (it's much more manageable)

[image]

Has anyone come up with a *useful* common_timezone list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Useful"* is opinionated.  Your opinions may not match with others'.  For example, the list in your example doesn't have an entry for Arizona - which is not the same as just Mountain Time, as it doesn't have daylight saving time.

The better approach is to offer *two* dropdowns.  The first should list countries, and the second would list time zones within the country.  Since many countries only have a single time zone, many users won't need to select time zones at all.  Those that do can limit their choice to a much smaller list.

In pytz, you can use the `country_timezones` function to get a list of time zones for a particular country.

Comment: Yea that's a good point. Thanks for the input, I'll go with your suggestion.